# Realtime clock written on image using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write real time clock on image. I have simple running code for using while loop and cv2.putText() command. But the problem with this code is that i am getting overwrite numbers of the time value.
Can anyone help me with same. Help appreciated in advance.

```
import cv2
import time

I = cv2.imread('image.png')
I = cv2.resize(I,(640,480))
I1 = I.copy()
font1 = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

while 1:
     I1 = I
     t = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
     I1 = cv2.putText(I1,t,(0,480),font1,2,(255,255,255),5)
     cv2.imshow('frame',I1)
     k = cv2.waitKey(10)
     if k == 27:
          break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV `cv2.putText()` change the input image in-place, To prevent this behaviour, you may try to pass input image as a `copy()`, so that the changes are not reflected in the original image itself.

```
while 1:
     I1 = I
     t = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
     I1 = cv2.putText(I1.copy(),t,(50,50),font1,2,(255,0, 0),5)
     cv2.imshow('frame',I1)
     k = cv2.waitKey(10)
     if k == 27:
          break
```

However, there are some redundant steps in your script, which can be stripped without affecting the output as:

```
import cv2
import time

I = cv2.imread('image.png')
font1 = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

while 1:
     t = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
     I1 = cv2.putText(I.copy(),t,(50,50),font1,2,(255,0, 0),5)
     cv2.imshow('frame',I1)
     k = cv2.waitKey(10)
     if k == 27:
          break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```